# Swift - Get attribute from Core Data Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This might sound confusing, but I will try to explain it the best I can.

I am trying to fetch a particular attribute from my Core Data and store the result in an array.

I have an entity called **Job** which is passed to my cameraController. I then have another entity called **Cameras** which has a relationship with **Job**.

These 2 entites are then passed to newCameraController. On this ViewController I am trying to fetch the attribute **cameraBody** which belongs to the **Cameras** entity.

This is how I am fetching the data at the moment:

```
var job: Job?
var cameras: Cameras?

func fetchCameraBodies() {
    guard let jobCameras = job?.cameras?.allObjects as? [Cameras] else { return }
}
```

This is returning all the camera attributes that belong to that job because of **.allObjects**. See below:

[image]

How do I fetch the single attribute that is related to that job instead of all the attributes and relationships and store them in an array?

Comment: In job‘s `.cameras` `Set` are multiple cameras which you all print. `allObjects` just returns an array of every object in the given set. You can try `jobCameras.forEach{ $0.cameraBody }` to print each camera‘s `cameraBody`-attribute in the `jobCameras`-array. You canget an array of cameraBodies with `let cameraBodies: [String] = jobCameras.map{ $0.cameraBody! }`

Comment: Thank you, **jobCameras.map** works perfectly